# Robotium for automation

Tags: automation, robotium

I am following Robotium guidelines for automating third party application.when i create android test application ,it is throwing null pointer exception.Even if I neglect it and try to run application ,it is throwing no application with that name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even I have tried a lot over this, but in vain. 
One of my friend suggested me to double click the finish button twice as fast as I can and I have done it. By  following this I have solved.. You too try once and check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you, but testing third party applications I've used testdroid-robotium. This creates a simple 'template' for the robotium quickly using your touch input from the device. From there you can edit the testcase to add the extras you need.

While following the tutorial for testdroid I haven't run into any null pointer exceptions. Maybe you can try this out and see if it helps?

edit- and then I see this was asked 1 year ago :)